# Power Bi Desktop Error Message: Each original name must belong to the set of all names

Tags: powerbi, relationship, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a query that imports two sheets from an xlsx file, combines the data, unpivots it, and does other cleanup steps. For the resulting fact table I also defined relations to 3 further dim tables.

Then I decided to **refactor the query in the PowerQuery editor**, including splitting the query up into 3 steps and disabling load of the the first two. (To play it safe I also stored my pbix w/o applying the steps.)

But then after a `Close & Apply` I got the following cryptic error message:

```
Something went wrong. 
Each original name must belong to the set of all names.
```

PBIDesktop version is 2.96.701.0 64-bit (August 2021)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the web I found people suggesting that the error might be related to specific PBIDesktop versions and that moving back to a previous version would solve the issue.

For me it was easier than that, though a bit mysterious:

1. In PowerQuery I **enabled load** for all sub-queries,
2. let it **apply all my steps** and the error message was gone.
3. Then back in PowerQuery I could **disable load** for the sub-queries w/o triggering the error again!

I hope that this might help someone somewhen.